# What is ($\Pi^1_1$-CA)${}+{}$BI? And what is ID${}_\omega$?

Tags: lo.logic

> **QUESTIONS.**
>
> (a) What is the formal system $(\Pi^1_1$-CA)${}+{}$BI?
>
> (b) And what is ID${}_\omega$, the formal theory of $\omega$-times iterated inductive definitions?

They are both mentioned in the following paper without any further explanations:

[W. Buchholz, An independence result for $(\Pi^1_1$-CA)+$BI$, *Annals of Pure and Applied Logic* 33, 131-155, 1987](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.420&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I asked this question [at math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966781/), but no one knows the answer there.

Comment: I couldn't find a freely accessible document defining the $ID_\nu$ systems, so I put a definition on the nLab [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/iterated+inductive+definitions). See also the references recorded therein.

Comment: Hi Ulrik, thanks for writing that explanation. I left you a question over there at the nLab forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BI = Bar Induction.

See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2270902 for the abbreviation

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_induction for the definition.

Comment: This, together with Ulrik's writeup on ID_nu systems that he mentions in his comment, answers my question.